# How to properly plot a histogram with dates using ggplot?

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram, ggplot2

I would like to create an interactive histogram with dates on the x-axis.
I have used ggplot+ggplotly.

I've read I need to use to pass the proper information using the "text=as.character(mydates)" option and sometimes "tooltips=mytext".

This trick works for other kinds of plots but there is a problem with the histograms, instead of getting a single bar with a single value I get many sub-bars stacked.
I guess the reason is passing "text=as.character(fechas)" produces many values instead of just the class value defining that bar.

How can I solve this problem?
I have tried  filtering myself the data but I don't know how to make this the parameters match the parameters used by the histogram, such as where the dates start for each bar.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotly)

Ejemplo <- data.frame(fechas = dmy("1-1-20")+sample(1:100,100, replace=T),
            valores=runif(100))

dibujo <- ggplot(Ejemplo, aes(x=fechas, text=as.character(fechas))) +  
  theme_bw() +  geom_histogram(binwidth=7, fill="darkblue",color="black") +
  labs(x="Fecha", y="Nº casos") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "weeks", date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y", 
  limits=c(dmy("1-1-20"), dmy("1-4-20"))) 

ggplotly(dibujo)
ggplotly(dibujo, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

As you can see, the bars are not regular histogram bars but something complex.
Using just ggplot instead of ggplotly shows the same problem, though then you woulnd't need to use the extra "text" parameter.

Comment: What is the purpose of `valores` in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, feeding `as.character(fechas)` to the `text = ...` argument inside of `aes()` will display the relative counts of *distinct* dates *within* each bin. Note the height of the first bar is simply a count of the total number of dates between 6th of January and the 13th of January.

After a thorough reading of your question, it appears you want the *maximum* date within each weekly interval. In other words, one date should hover over each bar. If you're partial to converting `ggplot` objects into `plotly` objects, then I would advise pre-processing the data frame before feeding it to the `ggplot()` function. First, group by week. Second, pull the desired date by each weekly interval to show as text (i.e., end date). Next, feed this new data frame to `ggplot()`, but now layer on `geom_col()`. This will achieve similar output since you're grouping by weekly intervals.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(13)
Ejemplo <- data.frame(fechas = dmy("1-1-20") + sample(1:100, 100, replace = T),
                      valores = runif(100))

Ejemplo_stat <- Ejemplo %>%
  arrange(fechas) %>%
  filter(fechas >= ymd("2020-01-01"), fechas <= ymd("2020-04-01")) %>%  # specify the limits manually
  mutate(week = week(fechas)) %>%                                       # create a week variable
  group_by(week) %>%                                                    # group by week
  summarize(total_days = n(),                                           # total number of distinct days
            last_date = max(fechas))                                    # pull the maximum date within each weekly interval            

dibujo <- ggplot(Ejemplo_stat, aes(x = factor(week), y = total_days, text = as.character(last_date))) +
  geom_col(fill = "darkblue", color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Fecha", y = "Nº casos") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) paste("Week", x))

ggplotly(dibujo)                    # add more text (e.g., week id, total unique dates, and end date)    
ggplotly(dibujo, tooltip = "text")  # only the end date is revealed
```

[image: plotly end date]

The "end date" is displayed once you hover over each bar, as requested. Note, the value "2020-01-12" is **not** the last day of the second week. It is the *last date* observed in the second weekly interval.

The benefit of the preprocessing approach is your ability to modify your grouped data frame, as needed. For example, feel free to limit the date range to a smaller (or larger) subset of weeks, or start your weeks on a different day of the week (e.g., Sunday). Furthermore, if you want more textual options to display, you could also display your *total number* of unique dates next to each bar, or even display the date ranges for each week.

Comment: Do you want it to show all dates as you hover over each section of the bin? If so, then why not suppress the black lines delimiting the relative counts within each bin?

Comment: I want it to show just one date at each bin, the end date of the interval.

Comment: Do you mean one date *per bin*? For example, hovering over the first bar should return "2020-01-12" or whatever the last date is within each weekly bin?

Comment: See my updated answer. It displays the end (last) date in a weekly interval.

Comment: This is similar to what I was doing but I hoped to get a simpler/automatic version with ggplot and geom_bar or geom_hist.
In fact I'm using ceiling_date(fechas,  unit="week", week_start = 1)  or whatever binsize instead of week and grouping by this value.

Comment: Nice you noticed the date showed is not the last of the week but the last of your dates on that interval. 
I need to check how to show the former.

Comment: Why not 'peel off' the last day of the week *within* the date range from the 1st of January through the 31st of March and then merge this with `Ejemplo_stat` data frame? Now you will have a count of the rows, the last *observed* date, and the last cutoff date delimiting the weeks. Note `geom_bar()` is grouping (i.e., counting) by default, but since you also feed your date to `text = ...` inside of `aes()`, software will assume you want a summary by *groups* of dates.

Comment: Try: `as.character(ceiling_date(last_date - 7, unit = c("week"), week_start = 0))`. This works with my code. It will delimit the weeks for you, giving you the last day in each weekly interval (i.e., 5th, 12th, 19th, etc.). Note I had to adjust the date variable to start at the beginning of the month. Though it may seem less efficient, it circumvents the default behavior of `geom_bar()`.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically align the x-axis ticks to the right of each bin?
I mean without manually searching for a number to shift it, because it will change for each problem.

Comment: Shift the bars left: `geom_col(..., position = position_nudge(x = -0.5))`. This works with any arbitrary number of time units.